# Setting the size of gtk scale

Tags: c, gtk

I've got problems with gtk scale.
I've got fixed widget where I placed horizontal scale. The problem is that the scale is very small and I don't know how to resize it to for example 100 pixels.
Below is my code:

```
wind = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(wind), 300, 300);

fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(wind), fixed);

button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button1");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button, 10, 20);

button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button2");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button2, 200, 20);

scale = gtk_scale_new_with_range(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 1);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), scale, 100, 40);
```

and here is how it looks like:

[image]

The scale is in the middle of the window and shows 0 value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution by myself:

g_object_set(scale, "width-request", 200, NULL);

Comment: The proper solution is almost certainly "Don't use GtkFixed". If you learn to use the box layout (that every other container in GTK uses) things like this typically Just Work and the result won't break every time the user changes window size, font size or one the many other things that can potentially break a fixed layout. More details about the problems in [GtkFixed documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFixed.html#GtkFixed.description)

Comment: The _other_ proper solution - orthogonal to whether or not `GtkFixed` is used (which you probably shouldn't!) - is to use `gtk_widget_set_size_request`. This is a more general instance of what I assume is a standard OOP maxim: Always use the most derived version of a method you have available. Directly setting a GObject property is, firstly, ugly - and might work in some cases but is at risk of omitting required stuff to be performed by the derived class (e.g. `Widget`), so it's not an advisable way to do this. That's why we override things, after all.